# What is a pixel when transforming html elements into the z plane?

Tags: css

I'm familiar with moving things with `position: relative;` and the unitless `z-index: 10;`, and it makes sense to me that z-index is unitless. However, I just learned about `transform`, specifically its `translate3d` function:

```
transform: translate3d(0px,0px,10px);
```

I'm confused that translate3d accepts pixels for the third parameter, as there *are* no pixels in the z direction. What is a pixel when transforming html elements into the z plane and why are they more useful than unitless values?

Answer (score 1):

Each pixel of positive **z** translation brings the element one pixel closer to you (in practice, enlarging it), without changing the element's layering order with respect to other elements.

`z-index` [(documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) values are integer values that determine how different elements stack in relation to each other.

In `translate3d(tx, ty, tz)` [(documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d) the `tz` value, like the `tx` and `ty` values, is a translating vector for moving the element in 3d space within its `z-index` layer. A positive `tz` will move the element towards you and a negative `tz` will move the element away from you.

You can think of `tz` z plane translation as a cousin of `scale()` [(documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) (which uses a unitless value, where "2" is "double"): it "zooms" the element and does not affect the `z-index` layering order.

Comment: Can I go as far as saying that z translation ONLY affects scale? It is simply a different syntax for the same effect? I just saw that the "computed" styling shows a `matrix3d` property rather than the `transform3d` property I set...

Comment: Nearly: You can say that z translation affects scale, the layman term, but not the `scale()`, the css property. The result of `translate3d(0,0,≠0)` will be similar to `scale(≠0)`, but it isn't actually the same thing: the `translate3d()` simulates moving the element towards you or away from you, while `scale()` actually scales it - presumably the underlying computations are different

Comment: Worth noting that there may be differences in how `translate3d()` and `scale()` affect crispness - for example, `translate3d()` is known to make text blurry in webkit (plenty of SO and Google results for that)

Comment: And I'm not coming up with any examples of the top of my head but could there be times when some other css transform interacts differently with `scale` than it does with `translate3d`? Will have to think about that

Comment: But shortest response to your comment: you can use `translate3d(0,0,≠0)` as a way of getting pixel control of scaling (the layman's term) as opposed to the percentage control afforded by `scale()`